# get the key of local in laravel trans

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, laravel-7

and i need something thats if i want to get use locale in laravel i did this ..

```
{{trans('language.add')}}
{{trans('language.my_word')}}
{{trans('language.save')}}
{{trans('language.edit_file')}}
```

and the locale language file is like this ..

```
<?php
return 
[
    'add' => 'Add',
    'my_word' => 'Any thing here',
    'save' => 'Save !',
    'edit_file' => 'Edit File',
]
```

now if i did this code in the blade

```
{{trans('language.edit_file')}}
```

the result will be

```
'Edit File'
```

now my question is how can i get the key using the word ..
i mean how can i access `edit_file` using `Edit File`
i want to access the value Instead of key to access the key
thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use array_flip.

The array_flip() function is used to exchange the keys with their associated values in an array.

```
$languages = Lang::get('language');
$languagesFlip = array_flip($languages);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
{{array_search('Edit file',trans('language'))}}
```

The result will be `edit_file`

I hope that is what you need.